# How to Scatter Plot Series using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this serie:

```
print series.head()
print type(series)
print series.index

year
1992    36.222222
1993    53.200000
1994    49.400000
1995    34.571429
1996    39.200000
Name: ranking, dtype: float64
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Int64Index([1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014], dtype='int64', name=u'year')
```

I'm trying to do a scatter plot, but I'm having trouble accessing the the index and values from the series.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I believe pandas series does not support kind='scatter' if looking t0 call .plot() on a series.

I believe Lev's answer is best and suitable for use with pandas. I use matplotlib pyplot and it works in similar way to his example.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.scatter(ser.index, ser)
plt.show()
```

Perhaps try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1)

year = [1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]
value = np.random.rand(23)

ser =  pd.Series(index = year,data=value)
df =ser.to_frame()

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['year','value']
df.plot(kind='scatter',x='year',y='value')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 63):

I think the easiest is:

For series

```
series.plot(style='.')
```

For dataframe

```
df.plot(x='x_col', y='y_col', style='.')
```

Comment: This is the simplest and fastest solution: no resetting of indexes or whatsoever needed. Very nice! :)

Answer (score 8):

Like this?

```
import pylab
pylab.scatter(series.index, series)
```

Comment: forgot to mention, using Pandas

Comment: This is best approach and perfectly fine for pandas.

Comment: This answered the question without looking at another library.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I found is to use `reset_index()`, it will return a dataframe, with the series index as a column. So this is a very cool way to transfrom a series to a dataframe.

Once you're using a dataframe you can use pandas plot function:

```
df = series.reset_index()
df.plot(x="x_col", y="y_col", kind="scatter")
```